# how to filter a view to only docs in a specified document set?

Tags: search, view, document-set

I would like to create a view in a SharePoint library that shows all documents in one or more designated document sets, in a flat format, with fields and sort order as specified (different from that of the default view for the library).

My difficulty is that I don't know how to filter on document sets. What I need is a search command that returns only docs in a specified document set, together with instructions on how to find the document-set-specific values for that doc set to be used as search targets.

I am a site manager but not an administrator, so I can't use any techniques that require access to the programming level.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible out the box. What you could do is to create the filtered view you need, then navigate to one of the document set, copy the url and add that url to the menu. But that will limit you to one document set.

Answer (score 1):

Try with a content query web part maybe, but like Marek mention above it's not possible with Views

Answer (score 1):

If the document sets you want to show have a rational behind them then you can set a new field in the document set and have all items in the set inherit the column. If this is a “multiple selection” like a checkbox column then you can select a property for each document set and have a few that filters like this:

If  contains  AND
 is not “Document Set”

Then set the folders section to flat

You should just see the documents with the inherited column in the view. Unfortunately this isn’t dynamic. You’d need a view for each situation.

I’ll add an example when I get to a computer.